# Does Hartree Fock Approximation method work for bosons?

Tags: schroedinger-equation

HF method uses Slater Determinant, so we come up with the exchange energy, which gives me this understanding that HF approximation works for fermions as the exchange energy has the concept of Pauli exclusion principle in it. Is that correct? and if not, how can we use it for bosons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article on the Hartree-Fock method:

> The Hartree–Fock method often assumes that the exact, N-body wave function of the system can be approximated by a single Slater determinant (in the case where the particles are fermions) or by a single permanent (in the case of bosons) of N spin-orbitals. By invoking the variational method, one can derive a set of N-coupled equations for the N spin orbitals. A solution of these equations yields the Hartree–Fock wave function and energy of the system.

So yes, it works for bosons.